# Can mount using mount but not using /etc/fstab

Tags: 10.10, mount

I can mount my remote server home using:

```
mount servername:/home /mnt/home
```

but this only lasts until reboot.

I added the following the the end of `/etc/fstab`:

```
servername:/home /mnt/home
```

but I get an error while restarting saying mount failed. I opened the (recovery?) console as suggested by the error message, there I could see the server is not recognized. I also tried pinging its IP but it was unreachable. Perhaps this is because we're using a proxy?

So, what can I do to mount this location permanently?

Comment: Is that an NFS share?

Comment: Please copy-paste all error messages to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entries in `/etc/fstab` normally have four to six fields; I'm not sure if omitting the third field (filesystem type) and fourth field (options) will work. Try

```
servername:/home  /mnt/home  nfs  auto
```

In fact one problem I can foresee is that since the filesystem type is not present, the boot scripts try to mount the filesystem too early. If you explicitly specify a network filesystem, that filesystem is mounted only when the network is up.

Comment: No field could be left out in fstab, it is just their position that render them meaningful.

Comment: @enzotib: It's the position from the left that counts, so you can leave out the *rightmost* few fields. This is commonly done for fields 5 and 6 (which have to do with dumps and fsck order and are only needed for main OS partitions).